# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Deduplication by Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting, dynamic-arrays

I've done a lot of searching but cant find a good solution.

I have a dynamically generated array such as this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => a )
    [1] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => aa ) )
    [2] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aaa ) ) )
    [3] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aab ) ) )
    [4] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [ab] => Array ( [0] => aba ) ) )
    [5] => Array ( [0] => b )
    [6] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [0] => bb ) ) )
```

What I want to do is remove all duplicate values at each level (the array may be larger or smaller dimensionally) to create output similar to this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aaa
                                                  [1] => aab ) 
                                  [ab] => Array ( [0] => aba )
                                )
                 )
    [1] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [0] => bb )
                 )
      )
```

I've tried creating several recursive functions (example below) to deal with it but have as yet been unable to figure out how to get the desired effect, and have deleted all of them due to failure.

```
function deduplicateArray(&$varTemp) }
  if (is_array($varTemp)) {
    foreach($varTemp as $key => &$value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
        // do stuff.
        deduplicateArray($value);
      } else {
        // do stuff.
      }
    }
  } else {
    // do stuff.
  }
}
```

Even just a point in the right direction would help, thanks.

Edit:

The array is generated by this code which is created from appropriately named files using %2F as a Delimiter.

```
function generateStructure(&$arrStructure, $strContent, $strBaseURL, $strPageURL) {     // Generate Content Structure Code.
  if ($arrStructure === array(NULL)) {
    $arrStructure = array('');                           // Define Final Array.
    if ($dirTemp = opendir($strContent)) {
      while (false !== ($strFile = readdir($dirTemp))) {
        if ($strFile != '.' && $strFile != '..') {
          if (is_file($strContent.$strFile) && substr_count($strFile, '.php') > 0) {  // Make sure is file and is php.
            if (isset($arrFiles)) {
              array_push($arrFiles, strtok($strFile, '.php'));
            } else {
              $arrFiles = array(strtok($strFile, '.php'));
            }
          }
        }
      }
      closedir($dirTemp);
    } else {
      errorCode(403);
    }
    sort($arrFiles); // Put in Alphabetical Order
    $intTemp = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrFiles); $i++) {
      $arrTempSplit = explode('%2F',$arrFiles[$i]);        // Create an Array of Strings from FileName String by Delimiter.

      $ii = count($arrTempSplit) - 1;                      // Create integer that is equal to the potential Multi-Dimensional Array's Columns.
      //if ($ii > $intTemp) {
      //  $intTemp = $ii;                                    // Get highest elementt for The Final Array.
      //}

      $arrTemp=array($arrTempSplit[$ii]);                  // Turn current Element into Array.
      $ii--;

      for($ii; $ii >= 0 ; $ii--) {                         // Loop through the Multi-Dimentional Array from Right to Left.
        $arrTemp2 = array($arrTempSplit[$ii] => $arrTemp);
        unset($arrTemp);
        $arrTemp = &$arrTemp2;
      }

      // Deduplicate Multi-Dimensional Array.
      //if ($i > 0 && is_array($arrStructure[$i])) {
      //  $arrStructure[$i] = array_merge_recursive($arrTemp, $arrStructure[$i-1]);
      //} else {
        $arrStructure[$i] = $arrTemp;
      //}
    }
    //$arrStructure = array_unique($arrStructure);
    deduplicateArray($arrStructure);
    print_r($arrStructure);
  }
}
```

Its ok for the topmost array to not exist as [0][1][2] and so forth and just be the next level directly.

Also it is possible to have this scenario in the file names the table is generated

a%2Faa
aa%2Fa
bb%2Fb
b%2Faa%2Fa

I merely have them ordered in the order they are just now to make it easier to debug.

@erwin-haasnoot

the intended behavior would be

```
Array (    
        [0] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aab ) 
                                      [ab] => Array ( [0] => aba ) 
                                    )
                       [b] => Array ( [0] => abb )
                     )
        [1] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [0] => bba ) ) 
      )
```

The way to think of it is the left most value is from left to right the string is parent and child.

There may be no parent with the same name as another and a parent of that generation may not have any children that share a name.

However children may be the same name as their parent and as other children that belong to other parents.

Not all parents may have children.

Not all children may be parents in the next generation.

There is no limit to the amount of generations of Parent and Child.

Comment: What happens when you run array_unique on the top level array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Is there a danger of repeated keys between branches? For example, could there ever be a key `$array[6]['b']['aa']`?

Comment: @MatthewRiches Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a ) )

Comment: @DaveRandom yes that is a possibility.

Comment: @CyberAxe Is there any point in the top level of your output? Wouldn't it make more sense to have `Array ( [a] => Array ( ... ) [b] => Array ( ... ) )`?

Comment: @DaveRandom no, there's no point really, that's just how the array is created, I was going to attempt to strip that out.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not allowed to reply yet, I'll have to do it in an answer.

I don't think your problem is very well defined, for example, what would be the expected behaviour in this case? (Look at the array where the value is 'a' instead of the key):

```
Array (    
[0] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => aa ) )
[1] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aaa ) ) )
[2] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aab ) ) )
[3] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [ab] => Array ( [0] => aba ) ) )
[4] => Array ( [0] => a )
[5] => Array ( [0] => b )
[6] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [0] => bb ) ) )
```

Do numerical 'keys' (which indices basicly are, or can be) get thrown out? Or does it overwrite the array where key = 'a'

What is the intended behaviour for arrays like this:

```
Array (    
[0] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [aa] => Array ( [0] => aab ) ) )
[1] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [ab] => Array ( [0] => aba ) ) )
               [b] => Array ( [0] => abb )
[2] => Array ( [b] => Array ( [0] => bba ) ) 
)
```

And I'm sure I can think of many other examples that aren't covered by your own example. If you can think these through I think you'll be one step closer to your actual solution.

Comment: I've updated the question to show this scenario and hopefully cover all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

this function will help, I'm still working on how exactly.

**EDIT: SOURCE: http://sebastiano.ezion.cc/2008/03/13/php-foreach-function-for-multi-level-arrays/#**

```
$buff = "";  
function foreach_loop($array) {  
global $buff;  

    foreach ($array as $key => $value ) {  
        if (!is_array($value)) { // if it isn't an array show $key and $value  
                $buff .= '   ' . $key; 
                $buff .= '  ->  ' . $value . '<br> '; 
        }else {  // if it is an array -> show $key -> then process $value again will same function. 
                $buff .= '<strong>' . $key.'</strong> ';  
                foreach_loop($value);  
        }  
    }  
}  

foreach_loop($oldarray);
echo $buff;
```